# Using Auto-py-to-exe with MULTIPROCESSING lib: UndefinedEnvironmentName: 'extra' does not exist in evaluation environment

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyinstaller, gevent, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to create an .exe of my python application that I run from the `server.py` script. I am using `Auto-py-to-exe` in **one directory mode** which gives me the following command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --icon "path" --name "name" --add-data "path" --add-data "path" --add-data "path" --hidden-import "openpyxl.cell._writer " --exclude-module "gevent server.py"  "C:/Users/140476/Documents/57956_EXE_ANALISIS_DATO_TALADRADO/server.py"
```

Those are my versions:

```
6067924 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.0.0
6067938 INFO: Python: 3.9.13 (conda)
6067956 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.40.0
```

I receive the following error:

```
6258721 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\packaging\markers.py", line 215, in _get_env
    raise UndefinedEnvironmentName(
packaging.markers.UndefinedEnvironmentName: 'extra' does not exist in evaluation environment.

Project output will not be moved to output folder
Complete.
```

Previously, I could make the .exe in my python project. Now I have added with `pysimplegui` a file explorer that uses the `Multiprocessing` library. Therefore, it makes me think that the failure could be related to this library. When I run it from console it works perfectly.

Attached are some parts of my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
                # On Windows calling this function is necessary.
       freeze_support()
```

```
def interact_callbacks(self):
    @callback(
        Output('add-automatically-button', 'children'),
        Input('add-automatically-button', 'n_clicks')
    )
    def update_output(n_clicks):
        freeze_support()
        if n_clicks is not None:
            print('before process')
            p = Process(target=startInteraction)
            p.start()
            return 'Clicked!'
        else:
            return 'Add automatically'
```

Any kind of help is welcome, as I have no idea how to deal with this problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error message using PyInstaller on Linux, but I could imagine the cause in your case could also be the use of virtual Anaconda environments.
What solved the issue in the end for me, was to install PyInstaller via `conda` instead of `pip` within the virtual environment (as also mentioned in a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494470/python-executable-by-pyinstaller-in-virtual-conda-environment-dll-load-failed?r=SearchResults_Semantic)).
As Auto-py-to-exe is built on PyInstaller it might also help to try

```
conda install PyInstaller
```

or, if it exists, a conda package of Auto-py-to-exe. However, this is just a guess, I haven't tried this on Windows.